# How to run an external javascript from javascript with attributes and get object

Tags: javascript, external, payment, setattribute

This is the code to open a window and ask for the credit card info.
But i have to open a web page first, that's what i don't want.

```
echo '<script src="https://evopaymentsmexico.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.js" data-error="errorCallback" data-cancel="cancelCallback"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                function errorCallback(error) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
                function cancelCallback() {
                      console.log("Payment cancelled");
                }
                Checkout.configure({
                  session: { 
                    id: "' . $sessionid . '"
                    },
                 interaction: {
                        merchant: {
                            name: "Your merchant name",
                            address: {
                                line1: "200 Sample St",
                                line2: "1234 Example Town"            
                            }    
                        }
                   }
                });
                Checkout.showLightbox();
</script>';
```

I'm trying to directly run the code on javascript, not on PHP.
So i don't open another page.

The problem is "Checkout" object is never created.

Here's my code:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

    scriptTag.setAttribute("data-error", "errorCallback");
    scriptTag.setAttribute("data-cancel", "cancelCallback");

    scriptTag.src = "https://evopaymentsmexico.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/57/checkout.jss";
    //eval(scriptTag);     it doesn't work, Checkout object is not created.
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);   it doesn't work either, same thing.

    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    function cancelCallback() {
        console.log("Payment cancelled");
    }
    Checkout.configure({
        session: {
            id: "' . sessionid . '"
        },
        interaction: {
            merchant: {
                name: "Your merchant name",
                address: {
                    line1: "200 Sample St",
                    line2: "1234 Example Town"
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Checkout.showLightbox();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your code is executed before the script tag is loaded. You need to wait: `scriptTag.onload = function() { /* Here, Checkout is available */ };`. Also, don't forget to convert this line to JS: `id: "' . sessionid . '"` (`+` instead of `.`, and that variable needs to exist)

Comment: no checkout.jss, but checkout.js